# Can I view a memory before the Captured Memories Quest?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I stumbled upon the Lanayru Road East Gate memory location prior to completing the Locked Mementos quest. I have collected the camera rune from Purah, now the quest states:

> You proved the Camera works again by capturing an image of Purah! According to Purah, the album already has pictures from the past in it. Where could these have come from? Impa in Kakariko Village may have the answer.

I was wondering if I would be able to view the memory, however, no memory shows up. See image below:

[image: Lanayru Road - East Gate No Memory]

I then spoke to Impa to complete the quest and receive the Captured Memories quest and sure enough, the memory is available. [image: Lanayru Road - East Gate Memory Available]

Do I have to complete the Locked Mementos quest prior to being able to view the memories?  If this is the case, I just think it is unfortunate that you have to back track to Kakariko village before being able to see the memories even though the memories are on the Sheikah Slate. If this is not the case, are the memories available at certain times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes.

The idea is that Impa is the one helping you to restore your memories, not Purah. As far as Purah is concerned, she's only interested in the Slate itself, not Link; Impa is the one that give the quest, which makes the memory locations appear.

This is partially because [Pikango](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Pikango) who is first encountered in Kakariko Village, will help you locate some of the memory locations (it's not necessary to talk to him, it's just the game giving you some help).

However, as far as "backtracking" goes, you can fast travel between shrines which should make the travelling around a little less troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

## Sometimes

The "yellow sparkles" memories, like the one pictured, are not accessible before obtaining the Captured Memories quest.

## However...

During all four of the Divine Beast quests, you recover a memory of the corresponding Champion. These **do not** count towards Captured Memories and therefore also do not require Captured Memories to be started. Also, in the Champions' Ballad DLC, after hearing each Champion's song, you will recover another memory of the Champion. Finally, at the end of the Champions' Ballad DLC, after Kass plays the Champions' Ballad, you will recover one last "non-Captured Memories" memory (EX Recovered Memory #5 - The Champions' Ballad).